# Animating changes to @FocusState SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui

I am using the new @FocusState to control how my views react to the user deciding to start inputting information into text fields. My current need is to wrap an animation around my top view leaving the screen as the keyboard moves up. Usually this kind of thing can be accomplished by simply wrapping `withAnimation()` around a boolean toggle, but since Swift is toggling my focus state bool under the hood, I can't wrap an animation around it in this way. How else should I do it?

Here is a minimal reproducible example. Basically I want to animate the top (red) view leaving / coming back into view with changes to my focus state `isFocused` var.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                if !isFocused {
                    Text("How to Animate this?")
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 5), value: isFocused)
                }
            
                Text("Middle Section")
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                    .background(Color.green)
            
                Spacer()
            
                TextField("placeholder", text: $text)
                    .focused($isFocused)
            
            }
        
            if isFocused {
                Color.white.opacity(0.1)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isFocused = false
                    } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think the animation modifier that's currently on the top view is doing anything, but I imagine that that's where I'll put some animation code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that works. I've done this before to make an animation happen upon an `@FocusState` property changing its value. Can't really tell you why though, it's just something I figured out with trial and error.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool
    @State private var showRedView = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                if !showRedView {
                    Text("How to Animate this?")
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                        .background(Color.red)
                }
                
                Text("Middle Section")
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                    .background(Color.green)
                
                Spacer()
                
                TextField("placeholder", text: $text)
                    .focused($isFocused)
                
            }
            .onChange(of: isFocused) { bool in
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 5)) {
                    showRedView = bool
                }
            }
            
            if isFocused {
                Color.white.opacity(0.1)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isFocused = false
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```